# SQLite: Add column with primary key to existing table whilst persisting data

Tags: database, sqlite, unique-constraint

Within the context of SQLite.

I have an existing table which is currently populated with numerous rows of data.

I am trying to add a new primary key column to this table whilst persisting the original data.

As demonstrated below, I have tried the following

1. Add a new column to the existing table (Id INTEGER).
2. Change the name of the existing table.
3. Create a new table which includes the new primary key (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY).
4. Insert all data from the renamed table into the newly created table.
5. Drop the renamed table.

The reason I thought this would work is because according to SQlite documentation,

> A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

However I am receiving the following error.

```
ErrorCode : 19
Message   : constraint failed
UNIQUE constraint failed: Person.Id
Result    : Constraint
```

Here is my code.

```
--Add a new column to the existing table(Id INT).
ALTER TABLE [Person]
ADD Id INTEGER;

--Change the name of the existing table.
ALTER TABLE [Person] RENAME TO Person_temp;

--Create a new table which includes the new PK.
CREATE TABLE Person(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(100) NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(100) NULL
);

--Insert all data from the renamed table into the new table.
INSERT INTO Person SELECT * FROM Person_temp;

--Drop the renamed table.
DROP TABLE Person_temp;
```

Could anyone be kind enough to shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not declare column names in your insert query, the column order depends on the order in witch they where created / added. Try to specify the column names. This is usually a good practice anyway

```
--Insert all data from the renamed table into the new table.
INSERT INTO Person(Id, FirstName, LastName) SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Person_temp;
```

By the way, you probably don't need to add the `Id` column in the first table :

```
--Insert all data from the renamed table into the new table.
INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName) SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Person_temp;
```

the implicit null value for `Id` will be replaced by the autoincrement

Comment: Just what I was looking for. You were also right in saying I probably didn't need the Id column in the first table. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It sure seems like your Id column does not contain unique value in each row. Since you just added the column, each row will have the same value.

The auto increment is there to help when you insert new rows. (You don't have to select max(id), and insert the new row with id = max+1). It won't auto-populate an existing table of data.

SQLite already has a column that could work for what you want. It's called ROWID. Try using that instead of duplicating it with your Id column.

Comment: Although this was helpful, the answer by bwt was more complete. Once my reputation is at 15 I will make sure to come back and mark this answer as useful. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sure thing Brandon. Glad you found a solution.